# passwordless ssh to remote system as root

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I need to ssh (as root) to a remote server and perform some root level operations. I will be sshing from a local server where I don't have root privileges. Given this option, is it possible to perform passwordless ssh to remote system using (rsa) keys ?

Local and remote servers run linux.

BTW, I generated keys (ssh-keygen -t rsa) on the local server. Copied the public key to remote server's .ssh/authorized_keys file. **However it still keeps prompting for password.** The same setup works fine, if the local and remote username (non-root) matches.

Comment: This is off-topic.  But it's also unclear what it is that you're asking.  You can SSH into the server from anywhere as root using `ssh root@myserver` (or whatever user-name), but you can't avoid some form of authentication...  Authentication using SSH keys is widely documented...

Comment: I am using private keys (ssh-keygen -t rsa). However it keeps prompting for password

Comment: Are you adding the public key to `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` file ? Also what is the `ssh` command you ran to login as root ? It should be something of the form `ssh root@server` to ensure that ssh knows you're trying to login as the user `root` on the remote machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 check that your /etc/ssh/sshd_config file have  "PermitRootLogin yes".

2 Store the following Shell code into nopasswd.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

scp ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub  $1@$2:~/
ssh $1@$2 "cat ~/id_dsa.pub  >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys; chmod 644 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys; exit"
```

3 Use it by these steps:

```
$ssh-keygen -t dsa
$ ./nopasswd.sh root REMOTE_HOST
```

Comment: Thanks - this fixed the issue! "PermitRootLogin Yes"

Comment: great script; though, i had to edit it a bit

Comment: Thanks you saved me! :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. SSH does not make a connection between account names on different systems, so you can ssh as non-root to root if you have a valid key pair.

Answer (score 0):

In ~/.ssh/config:

```
Host rootRemoteSystem
HostName RemoteSystem
User root
```

Then:

```
ssh-copy-id rootRemoteSystem
```

Then you can do:

```
ssh rootRemoteSystem
```